# SP 2013 Log Viewer?

Tags: 2013, file

does anybody know if there is already a log viewer tool available that can completely read SharePoint 2013 log files?
As far as i know the 2010 log viewer tools can't parse the log files of 2013 and i have not found anything during my google search.

Any help would be nice!

Best regards

Comment: My favorite one: https://ulsdeobfuscator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is the same, only the location is different, it's not anymore in the 14 hive but on the 15 hive so you need to point ULS to that hive instead (open ULS Viewer and then hit `CTRL+U`

[image]

Comment: i already tried that, but then as a message there is always an error that the line could not be understood: "UlsRuntimePump could not understand this line:" and then following the line of the log file

Comment: Detailed exception is a Dateformat exception in every line that is read by ULS Viewer

Comment: You're using the RTM binaries ? or the Customer Preview ?

Comment: RTM, but as far as i can remember it did neither work in customer preview

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Saw that I'm not the only one using it : https://twitter.com/jaysimcox/statuses/225724542692241409 and the Log Viewer mentionned by Seb (which is also nice since it rolls up from all WFEs) is following the same way to parse them.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i found what the problem was with ULS Viewer. The problem is not one of Sharepoint 2013 but occurs because my Server / SharePoint language is not set to EN_US. This is a problem for ULS Viewer when it comes to parsing the date in the log file. There is a fix available: [ULS Viewer Fix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ulsviewerfix/) , someone also suggested that changing system language could help.

Comment: You should really challenge the one who made the installation on a system other then en-us. Get ready for a bunch of troubles later on (spent so many times with *tiny* issues like that on french configured server & sp install)... Good luck anyway and thanks for pointing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with [SharePoint Log Viewer](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) and it seems to work great.

Comment: you are right, SharePoint Log Viewer can read the logs without problem. Any idea how i can set the path to the ULS so that live watching also works?

Comment: I don't use this feature, most of the time i do a refresh using column filters and I can find my troubles easily.

Comment: I like this coz you can filter based on Category. Very useful :)!